# Running Cordova sample project with CocoonJS Launcher

Tags: android, cordova, cocoonjs

Does anyone know for sure if the CocoonJS Launcher android app is capable of running Cordova projects without previous compilation?

I'm trying to follow this [**guide**](http://support.ludei.com/hc/en-us/articles/201895066-Getting-Started-with-Cordova-and-CocoonJS) to the letter but CocoonJS Cloud compiler is temporary out of service for Cordova projects. So after step 6, I try to run the sample project using the CocoonJS Launcher app.

Unfortunately opening the `helloracoon.zip` with the launcher (Your Cordova -> WebView+) looks like this:

[image: Cordova sample running in CocoonJS Launcher]

The "Connecting to device" message means the Cordova API (`deviceready` event) doesnt seem to work. I find this a bit strange cause if Cordova projects weren't meant to work with CocoonJS Launcher, there wouldn't be an option in the main menu..

So, am I doing something wrong?

**PS:** I am using `Cordova 3.2.0-0.1.0` just like the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code generated by default by Cordova for a new project doesn't include the needed cordova.js file. You have to copy it manually to the www folder root. The other choice is to zip the folder `<whatever>/<project>/platforms/android/assets/www`. In this folder Cordova puts the full project, including a copy of www and the cordova.js file.

Please, update to the latest version of CocoonJS Launcher app.

Comment: Worked after the latest update! Also I'll be using the `/platforms/android/assets/www` folder for my zip for now on and after I've built my project from CLI (`cordova build`).

Comment: Could you also assist me, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507394/cordova-plugins-cocoonjs-compass-error-class-not-found please? Thanks in advance!