# CocoonJS & Cordova plugins: "class not found" error

Tags: android, cordova-plugins, cocoonjs

I would be glad if we had an example on how cordova plugins should be wrapped for CocoonJS.

I'm trying to use the device-orientation plugin (compass) in a simple example but after the app has initialized, the `navigator.compass.getCurrentHeading()` returns an [CompassError](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.2.0/cordova_compass_compass.md.html#CompassError) with the code:

```
Class not found
```

The class name cannot be resolved correctly, so probably something's wrong with the config.xml file.

After combining many sources, mine looks like this:

**../www/config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="my.compass.html" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloCordovaCompass</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that displays the current compass heading after the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="a@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />   
    <feature name="App">
       <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
    </feature>      
    <feature name="Compass">
       <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.deviceorientation.CompassListener" />
    </feature> 
</widget>
```

I've also tried to include compass as plugin:

```
<plugin name="Compass" value="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
```

with no difference..

**PS:** The app works fine on plain Cordova.

**[UPDATE]**

Maybe the problem is here:

For this example I zipped the `<project-name>/platforms/android/assets/www` folder.

I'm not sure if this is enough for a Cordova plugin app, as the native code of the plugin is not included (`CompassListener.java`) and the only part that seems to work is actually its JavaScript interface (`compass.js`, `CompassError.js`, etc)..

On the other hand, If I try to zip the whole `<project-name>` directory as pointed out at the bottom of [**this**](http://support.ludei.com/hc/en-us/articles/201895066-Getting-Started-with-Cordova-and-CocoonJS) tutorial, the CocoonJS Launcher crashes..

So, could at least someone confirm that the launcher can actually compile Cordova plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use plugins you have to zip all Cordova project folders. Example:

```
cd ~/projects/ && zip -r -X hellococoonfull.zip helloCocoonJS && cd -
```

See the section "Using Cordova Plugins" of [Getting Started with Cordova and CocoonJS](http://support.ludei.com/hc/en-us/articles/201895066-Getting-Started-with-Cordova-and-CocoonJS) guide.

**[Update]**

The CocoonJS Launcher is not ready for plugins yet. For using plugins you have to use de cloud compilation system.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up, @user2477849! Do you know when the cloud compilation system will be open again to the public?

Comment: Very soon @LePhleg! :-)